# Why should I use v-bind for style

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I just started learning Vue and I was wondering, why should I use v-bind for style and not write it regularly in html/css file

Comment: `v-bind` is a general way of handling attributes in Vue. Since classes and styles are both attributes, they are used with `v-bind`. See the docs here maybe: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Comment: Some dynamic style can't be define with css class ,eg: Current position in the progress bar etc,you need use v-bind:style

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you need to create a progress bar that is not static. You will then need to update the style attribute `width` for-example.

To accomplish this, we need to programatically edit the `width` of the element. We 'cannot' to this in plain css, therefore the `:style` attribute comes in handy.

Let's create an example:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/BlitZZ96/pen/aGrqLw)

HTML

```
<div id="vue">
  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div :style="{'width':progress + '%'}" class="progress" />
  </div>
  <button @click="fakeProgress">Init fake progress</button>
</div>
```

Css;

```
.progress-bar, .progress {
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 20px;
} 
.progress-bar {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.progress {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

Javascript

```
new Vue({
  el: '#vue',
  data: {
    progress: 0
  },
  methods: {
    fakeProgress() {
      let progress = setInterval(() => {
        if(this.progress == 100) {
         clearInterval(progress) 
        } else {
         this.progress += 1;
        }
      }, 50)
    }
  }
})
```

As you see here, we bind the progress data attribute to the width value on the fake progress bar. This is just a simple example, but I hope this makes you see its potential. (You could achieve this same effect using the `<progress>` tag, but that would ruin the explanation.

EDIT; Also want to point out that you **are** supposed to write all your css as normal as you point out in your question. However, `:style` is used in cases that you cannot normally use css for. Like the example above where we need css to change from a variable.